Spring Boot Config Server/Client - URL must start with 'jdbc'
I somehow can't tell my client to read the configs correctly.
To make it short, my Spring Config Server (SCC) works correctly and with http / curl I can access the configurations correctly. For my dev environment I do have in my remote branch "dev" this application-dev.yml in my SSC:
# Common Configurations - Datasource
mysql:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
  username: root
  password: test-password

jpa:
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
  show-sql: true

test:
  database:
    replace: none

# Location Service
EMP_LOC-S:
  schema: location_db

# Employee Service
EMP_EMP-S:
  schema: employee_db

# Customer Service
EMP_CUS-S:
  schema: ${EMP_SCHEMA_CUSTOMER}

# Supplier Service
EMP_SUP-S:
  schema: ${EMP_SCHEMA_SUPPLIER}

# Inventory Service
EMP_INV-S:
  schema: ${EMP_SCHEMA_INVENTORY}

# Product Service
EMP_PRD-S:
  schema: ${EMP_SCHEMA_PRODUCT}

Here is my "application-dev.yml" in my Spring Config Client - Location-Service (LOC-S).
# Connecting with Spring Cloud Config Server (CNF-S) - dev environment
spring:
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:${BASE_URL}:8888
  cloud:
    config:
      label: dev
      uri: ${BASE_URL}:8888
      username: ${EMP_CONFIG_USERNAME}
      password: ${EMP_CONFIG_PASSWORD}

# Datasource configuration for MySQL Server - LocationDB
  datasource:
    url: ${mysql.url}/${EMP_LOC-S.schema}
    username: ${mysql.username}
    password: ${mysql.password}

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: ${jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}
    show-sql: ${jpa.show-sql:true}

  test:
    database:
      replace: ${test.database.replace}

But unfortunately I do get this error here:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:111) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:284) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.getDriverClassName(PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0

I was looking for the root cause, but I simply can't figure it out.
Thank you all for the support and I hope this isn't a duplicate.
Peace!

I'm not sure that the same properties file can both define the config server and simultaneously inject properties from the config server.  Your dev properties defined in your config server should define datasource.url; there's no need for interpolation

Hi @lane.maxwell,
so you mean I need to define only "spring.datasource.url" etc. in the application-dev.yml of my Config Server and in my Config Client (Location-Service) only the simple import is necessary ->
spring:
config:
import: optional:configserver:${BASE_URL}:8888
I have to build the correct connection since I need to concatenate the properties for my "spring.datasource.url".

If you're using the config server, then the only configuration you need in your properties file is the properties required to connect to the config server.  Then, you simply define all of your properties in the config server.  Hope this helps

Ok, I somehow could manage it with the help of ChatGPT and @laneMaxwell hints.
I've created a service specific yml file in my config server (CNF-S for simplicity).
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/location_db
    username: root
    password: ******
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  test:
    database:
      replace: none

server:
  port: 8080

In my config client application - Location Service (LOC-S) I've created a single bootstrap.yml file which fetches the configurations from "location-service.yml" of my CNF-S. And then it worked.
bootstrap.yml of LOC-S
# Basic configs - Name & Profile
spring:
  application:
    name: Location
  profiles:
    active:
      - ${ENVIRONMENT}

# Connecting to CNF-S - Configuration Server
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:${BASE_URL}:8888
  cloud:
    config:
      label: ${ENVIRONMENT}
      uri: ${BASE_URL}:8888
      name: location-service
      username: ${EMP_CONFIG_USERNAME}
      password: ******!

# Configuring Port for Location-Service
server:
  port: 8080

# Spring Actuator
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - health
          - info
      base-path: /actuator
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

By the way, it's also important to include this maven dependency in LOC-S.
pom.xml:
        <!-- Spring Bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

